# Create PHP array from MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql

I get data from MySQL query by using GROUP_CONCAT:

```
GROUP_CONCAT('id => ',assignments.userid,', assigned => ',assignments.assigned SEPARATOR ';') as assigneeids
```

And trying to convert it to PHP array.

```
$assignees = explode(';', $ticket['assigneeids']);
foreach($assignees as $assignee) {
    echo "$assignee\n"; // $assignee['id'] outputs 'i'
    echo gettype($assignee) . '\n';
}
```

But unfortunately `$assignee` becomes a string instead of array. Output:

```
id => 1001, assigned => 1419648601
string
id => 1002, assigned => 1419649207
string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you attempting to generate PHP code from a SQL query and expecting it to be evaluated as PHP? That won't work without `eval()`, but that is not the way to approach this. Can you clarify that your goal is to produce arrays with the 2D structure containing sub arrays `array('id' => 1234, 'assigned' => 987654)` ?

Comment: Yes, this is my goal.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the source table? You probably just need a simpler query with a normal fetch loop, but a little bit of array manipulation.  Is this GROUP_CONCAT() part of a larger query, or was it the only thing returned by your query?

Comment: This is a complicated query with multiple JOINs

Comment: Ok, post a bit more of the query then. Even if the query is complicated, the fetch process should still be simple. Or the query may need to be reorganized a little to allow the dimensions you need with the appropriate grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating it into a string, not an array. Would you not be better off doing something like this?

```
GROUP_CONCAT(assignments.userid,'_',assignments.assigned SEPARATOR ';') as assigneeids
```

Once fetched, you'll need to do some `explode()`'ing magic

```
$assignees = explode(';', $ticket['assigneeids']);
foreach($assignees as $assignee) {
    list($id, $assigned) = explode("_", $assignee);
    echo "$id\n";
    echo gettype($assigned) . '\n';
}
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#T60irvv7S)

Comment: That worked perfectly fine, but isn't this a little dirty workaround? =)

Comment: @AlexG Haha not exactly (*only a bit*), since you were on that path already! Since you want to create an array, you'd do more harm implementing `eval()`. Let PHP do your grunt work ! ;P

Comment: I just learned something new. I didn't realize you could put multiple expressions in `GROUP_CONCAT`. I've always written `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(x, y, z))`

Comment: It does look like I was on the wrong path, but my only other option is to do a separate query to get assignees, which is not cost effective....

Comment: @Barmar - *"In MySQL, you can get the concatenated values of expression combinations. ............... The default separator between values in a group is comma (“,”). To specify a separator explicitly, use SEPARATOR followed by the string literal value that should be inserted between group values. To eliminate the separator altogether, specify SEPARATOR ''."* - [Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) :-)

Comment: @Darren I'm talking about being able to write `GROUP_CONCAT(assignments.userid,'_',assignments.assigned)` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(assignments.userid,'_',assignments.assigned))`. I didn't know about that shortcut.

Comment: @Barmar: that's why it's called `GROUP`

Comment: @AlexG I know what GROUP_CONCAT does. I thought you could only do `GROUP_CONCAT(col1 SEPARATOR ';')`, I didn't know you could also do `GROUP_CONCAT(col1, col2, col3 SEPARATOR ';')`

Comment: That has nothing to do with why it's called `GROUP`, which refers to the fact that it concatenates the columns from all the rows in the `GROUP BY`, not to the fact that it can also concatenate columns in the same row as well.